# Цикл for пропускает элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Я создаю 2 цикла for, кодом:

```
like = ['123', '456']
with open(file = 'accounts.txt', mode = 'r') as accs:
    if len(like) > 1:
        for post in like:
            for date in accs:
                print(post)
```

Но почему-то выводится только 123, а 456 - нет. Почему? В accounts.txt указаны данные в формате "login:pass:token\n" в несколько строчек

Comment: Вы на первой итерации (`123`) зачитали весь файл. И на второй итерации (`456`) цикл `for date in accs:` вообще не срабатывает ни разу, т.к. больше читать из файла нечего. Как вариант, поменяйте два вложенных цикла `for` местами.

Comment: Решения проблемы я знал (поменять циклы местами), просто технически оно мне было не выгодно. Поэтому я обратился сюда, с мыслью, что будет более выгодное решение. Но зато я теперь знаю корень проблемы. Спасибо, попытаюсь решить другим способом

Comment: Ну, можно сделать файлу `seek` на начало (перед или после второго `for`). Тогда файл зачитается опять. Но обычно так не делают, т.к. работа с файлами идёт медленнее работы с данными в памяти, и делать повторный проход по файлу накладнее чем второй проход по списку.